# Get MagicalRecord NSManagedContext for use in background threads

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, magicalrecord, magicalrecord-2.2

I'm using MagicalRecord 2.2 and trying to run my fetch queries on a background thread by default but it seems that the documentation is outdates. Specifically it says:

```
If you need to create a new managed object context for use in non-main threads, 
use the following method:

NSManagedObjectContext *myNewContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_newContext];
```

However, the `MR_newContext` method is missing (guessing it was deprecated).There is a `[NSManagedObjectContext MR_context]` method but I'm not sure what context it returns. Drilling down into the code it creates a new context with concurrency type `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` so I'm guessing this is what I'm looking for.

Can anyone confirm this please?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use

```
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_confinementContext]
```

Though, as the CoreData team has effectively deprecated confinement contexts, this name may well change also.

Answer (score -2):

I think you better use `+ (NSManagedObjectContext *) MR_contextForCurrentThread;`. Its implementation seems just fine for your purposes:

```
+ (NSManagedObjectContext *) MR_contextForCurrentThread;
{
    if ([NSThread isMainThread])
    {
        return [self MR_defaultContext];
    }
    else
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *threadDict = [[NSThread currentThread] threadDictionary];
        NSManagedObjectContext *threadContext = [threadDict objectForKey:kMagicalRecordManagedObjectContextKey];
        if (threadContext == nil)
        {
            threadContext = [self MR_contextWithParent:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
            [threadDict setObject:threadContext forKey:kMagicalRecordManagedObjectContextKey];
        }
        return threadContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use this method. It *will* crash on you at random times.

Comment: Not recommended as detailed here: http://saulmora.com/2013/09/15/why-contextforcurrentthread-doesn-t-work-in-magicalrecord/